# "entre le marteau et l'enclume"

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

Pour traduire :

> It's difficult to see how to get out of this situation because we're between a rock and a hard place.

j'ai dis :

> Il est difficile de voir comment sortir de cette situation car οn est entre le marteau et l'enclume.

Peut-on utiliser couramment (dans un registre pas nécessairement soutenu) l'expression "entre le marteau et l'enclume" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Entre le marteau et l'enclume

ainsi que la variante que je trouve plus fluide

> Entre l'enclume et le marteau

sont utilisables mais restent plutôt soutenus.

On peut aussi dire :

> Être pris entre deux feux.

qui peut être utilisé quel que soit le registre, ainsi que les plus familiers :

> Avoir le cul entre deux chaises / Être assis entre deux chaises.

mais le sens est ici un peu différent.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **yes**

It will depend on the context, usually it is used when one is between two forces fighting, way much stronger than him/her, and might get injuries (of any kind) if staying in this position.